# iPhone Photo Smile Manipulation Applications

Tags: iphone, opencv, image-manipulation, image-recognition

I'm trying to create an iphone application that allows a user to take a photo of their smile, then drag and drop new smiles, from a small predefined list.

I know there are a lot of photo manipulation apps and I have seen similar concepts that allow smile manipulation, but not quite what I am looking for.  The problem is knowing where to start.  How can I create this effect? Would the OpenCV iPhone port be the best way to go?  Or perhaps something using OpenGL? Willing to do some research, but I find that experience often goes a long way, so any advice or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty cool application. I'd recommend some type of dense optical flow type alignment method which would be strike a balance between global consistency and local consistency.

In short, you'll want some generic mouth shapes in a gallery. Then, you can crop the user's mouth region and warp it to the gallery shape to show what their smile in that shape will look like.

[Ce Liu's Optical Flow implementation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/) might be an interesting point to start. You should be able to port that reasonably easily.